# ORDER BY with two columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I know I can order two columns with

```
ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 DESC
```

for example.

But in my case this doesn't work. I have a MySQL-Query, where I want to display events of the next days ordered by `date`, BUT also by a column named `highlight`.

Because there are 3 types of events: TOP-Premium (+++), Premium (++) and Free (+).

Now it orders like this:

-- < example >

```
7th May 2013

+FREE EVENT
++PREMIUM
+++TOP PREMIUM
+++TOP PREMIUM
```

--

```
8th May 2013
(same here as on 7th May 2013)
```

-- < / end of example >

So, as you can see, it orders by the next date is coming, which is correct! But I want to order the TOP-Premium-Events at the top, followed by the Premium-Events and at least the free events.

The end of my current non-working query is:

```
ORDER BY e.`date` ASC, e.`highlight` ASC");
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions!

Comment: maybe its being ordered alphabetically.. even if you are trying to order by date.. example: April 1 would be before January 1 because 'A' comes first than 'J'

Comment: @reikyoushin He said the date ordering is correct.

Comment: @Barmar which is weird anyway considering he uses DESC on date and get by ASC order.

Comment: @cheesemacfly He said _the end of my current non-working query is ORDER BY e.date ASC, e.highlight ASC_

Comment: @Barmar oups you're right, my bad :)

Comment: What is the data type of the `highlight` column? Is it ENUM?

Comment: @OP - You might want to clarify your question a small bit. Do you mean group by date: `7 May - Top, Prem, Free; 8 May - Top, Prem, Free` or by event type: `7 May Top, 8 May Top, 7 May Prem, 8 May Prem, 7 May Free, 8 May Free`? Your ORDER BY as-is does it by date.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, its: enum('2', '1', '0')

Comment: @Maple - The first one you mentioned in the post above my post (by date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ENUMs are represented internally as numbers, in the order that they were listed in the declaration.  If you declare a column as `ENUM('2', '1', '0')`, `'2'` is stored as `1`, `'1'` as `2`, and `'0'` as `3`.

ORDER BY uses those internal numbers, not the labels. If you want to order by the label, rather than the internal number, you have to use `CAST()`, e.g.

```
ORDER BY e.`date` ASC, CAST(e.highlight AS CHAR) ASC
```

This is one of the reasons why it's usually a bad idea to use numbers as the labels for an ENUM. The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) recommends against it.

Answer (score 3):

Uhm,

```
ORDER BY e.date ASC, e.highlight DESC
```

?

Comment: Interesting that they just happen to be in alphabetical order like that.

Comment: @Maple: Indeed. My answer is just based on an assumption that OP tells us the truth :-)

Comment: @Vay: "doesn't work" isn't a helpful explanation. If what you have explained in the question is correct - it should work. If it gives an unexpected result - you have made a mistake in the original issue explanation.

Comment: Because this seemed obvious to me that I've already tried that solution. I tried many ASC and DESC combinations with both columns. Maybe it's because of the fact that `highlight` is ENUM ('2','1','0') ?

Comment: @Vay: If the statement "So, as you can see, it orders by the next date is coming, which is correct! But I want to order the TOP-Premium-Events at the top, followed by the Premium-Events and at least the free events." is correct - then it should work. If it doesn't - you provided us with wrong issue explanation. "Maybe it's because" -- I'm not good enough in guessing today, change the question so that it provided **DETAILED** information about your schema and data. And provide them as-is, without any simplifications and so on

Comment: Maybe I'm not that good at explaining or describing it in another more understandable way, because English is not my mother-language. But what I actually mean is, that it orders correctly by date (upcoming dates), but in the opposite non-correct way by highlight-state (should be the opposite way).

Comment: @Vay: "but in the opposite non-correct way by highlight-state" --- so use `DESC` as I proposed. Is there a difference in output between `e.highlight DESC` and `e.highlight ASC`?

Comment: No it isn't. But now I've changed the datatype ENUM to tinyint(2) after reading many posts that ORDER with Enum is "evil". Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY e.date DESC, e.highlight ASC

Comment: Maybe it's because of the fact that `highlight` is ENUM ('2','1','0') ?

Answer (score 1):

Swap two columns - first order by `highlight` and then by date. You will get sequence like:

```
Top premium: 7th may
Top premium: 8th may
Premium: 7th may
Premium: 8th may
Free: 7th may
...
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of the fact that `highlight` is ENUM ('2','1','0') ?

Comment: It simple to verify - change type of `highlight` to INT