# ORDER BY two colums, but not sorting by time?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, sql-order-by

I've posted this question before and found a solution: [ORDER BY with two columns in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428598/order-by-with-two-columns-in-mysql/16444702?noredirect=1#16444702)

It's about sorting events. The priority SHOULD BE that TOP-PREMIUM and PREMIUM events are always on top of each date, no matter what.

The solution was that one column was ENUM and not INT. That's why he sorted wrong.

So now I'm sorting this way: `ORDER BY e.date ASC, e.highlight DESC`

Now I've another new problem, because all my dates were set to time 00:00:00 the time I asked the question here and thought it's all solved. If I'm setting the time to some hour after 00:00, it will be at the top of all events. Even in top of PREMIUM AND TOP-PREMIUM (highlight) events.

Can I somehow let MySQL ignore the time of the datetime type column `date` or is there any other way to make this work like I want to?

The problem also is that I can't order by highlight DESC first, because then the whole list won't be sorted by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CAST() function or the DATE_FORMAT function to get the date portion only, so this should work:

```
ORDER BY CAST(e.date AS DATE), e.highlight DESC
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(e.date, '%Y-%m-%d'), e.highlight DESC
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb620/2/0)

Edit: Updated sql fiddle demo to use 2 columns, you can see that the time portion of the date is not affecting sort order.

Comment: I've found another solution: ORDER BY CAST(e.date AS date) DESC, e.highlight DESC

Comment: I'd stick with CAST(), personally.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function, which strips the time component from a `DATETIME`:

```
ORDER BY DATE(e.date), e.highlight DESC
```

Comment: I've found another solution: ORDER BY CAST(e.date AS date) DESC, e.highlight DESC. Which solution is more efficient or reduces database work?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. My gut feeling is that there wouldn't be much - or any - difference between the two, but I'm not in a position where I can benchmark them. If this were for a `WHERE` clause on an indexed `DATETIME` column, I wouldn't use any of the solutions (mine included), but for an `ORDER BY` I don't think you'll see a noticeable difference.

Comment: You mean, you wouldn't CAST on WHERE clauses in general?

Comment: Not necessarily. I mean that if I had an index on a column and was hoping to have it optimize a `WHERE` clause, I wouldn't call *any* function on the column in the `WHERE` clause - I'd find a way to work with the "pure" column value instead. So `CAST` in this case would be out but so would `DATE` and `DATE_FORMAT`. But if optimization / indexes aren't in the mix there's no problem at all using `CAST`.